# laravel 5 edit elequent not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to edit my data field with following elequent but its not picking up the data, any help appreciated.

following is the data controller i am using:

```
  public function edit($name)
{

    $category = category::where('name', $name)->get()->all();

    dd($category);

    return view('/editcategory')->with('category', $category);

}
```

while checking the output it not picking up the data from the db
output:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => category {#190 ▼
    #table: "category"
    #connection: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    +timestamps: true
    #attributes: array:5 [▶]
    #original: array:5 [▶]
    #relations: []
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #fillable: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #casts: []
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
    #with: []
    #morphClass: null
    +exists: true
  }
]
```

Comment: what if you expand "attributes" or "original"?

Comment: cant grab you what you are exactly about

Comment: I mean click  "▶" of these two output tags:  #attributes: array:5 [▶]
#original: array:5 [▶]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use both `get()` and `all()` in the same time.
It should be:

```
public function edit($name)
{

    $category = category::where('name', $name)->all();

    [...]

}
```

Comment: [get  VS All](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587457/difference-between-eloquent-modelget-and-all) check this first