# Difference between Eloquent\Model::get() and all()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

What is the difference between uses `User::all()` and `User::get()` on Eloquent?

On Laravel API it describes only [`all()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_all) on `Eloquent\Model`.
Maybe [`get()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_get) is described on `Eloquent\Builder`.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

By themselves, `User::all()` and `User::get()` will do the exact same thing. However, there is a key difference.

`all()` is a static method on the `Eloquent\Model`. All it does is create a new query object and call `get()` on it. With `all()`, you cannot modify the query performed at all (except you can choose the columns to select by passing them as parameters).

`get()` is a method on the `Eloquent\Builder` object. If you need to modify the query, such as adding a where clause, then you have to use `get()`. For example, `User::where('name', 'David')->get();`.

Answer (score 12):

To further clarify why this works, it is because there is a magic method in the Model class which will take any static call that is not defined, create an instance, then call the method on the instance for you.

You can see it in the source code here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php  (line 1580)

This is also explained in this Laracast episode: https://laracasts.com/series/advanced-eloquent/episodes/3 (Subscription required)

I too was mystified when I first came across this and couldn't find `get()` as a static method. But then I recalled the Laracast episode which helped me connect the dots.

Comment: This is really a handy insight. I hadn't come across why that worked before. Laravel's magic under the hood can sometimes make you go "Huh?!"

Comment: Indeed! It’s one of the things that attracted me to it. 

Answer (score 8):

get() is used when you want to add queries and all() is used to get all data, without using any condition.

Example of all():

```
$query = Project::all();
```

Example of get():

```
$query = Project::select('id', 'name')->where('name', '')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel's Eloquent, both Eloquent\Model::get() and all() are methods used to retrieve all records from a database table. However, there is a subtle difference between the two

1.Eloquent\Model::get():

- The get() method is more versatile than all().
- It allows you to chain additional methods to modify the query before executing it. For instance, you can use get() along with where, orderBy, groupBy, and other query builder methods to filter, sort, or perform other operations on the retrieved data.
- It returns an instance of the Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection class, which provides additional methods for working with the retrieved data, like mapping, filtering, and more.

***Example:***
**$users = User::where('active', true)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();**

2.all():

- The all() method is a straightforward way to retrieve all records from the database table without any additional query builder operations. It fetches all the rows in the table as is.
- It is simple to use but lacks the flexibility of chaining additional query builder methods.

***Example:***
***$users = User::all();***

So, in summary, use get() when you need more control over the query or want to apply additional conditions, ordering, or grouping. Use all() when you want to fetch all records from the table without any extra query builder operations.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please make sure to read the [AI Policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1).  We hope you'll stick around and be a valuable member of our community by posting *your own* quality questions and answers - Thanks!