# Using Controller in Eloquent View gives error : htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to get data from a controller in my view to use in one of the div's

My TagController is like:

```
 class TagController extends Controller
{
//
    public function index(){
        $tags = Tag::all();
        return $tags;
    }
}
```

My view includes the following code to access this

```
{{ $tags = new App\Http\Controllers\TagController,
                        $tags->index()
}}
```

->can't use the keyword use because eloquent don't allow that
->Tried to make the function static and used TagController::index() , gave error
can't make function static
-> can't use this controller to route and redirect with the function because the view is already linked to another controller and i don't want to reload
How can I use this function from controller.
Sorry for this silly thing,  Please help out, I am new to laravel

Comment: `{{ }}` echo's with `htmlspecialchars` (therefore it expects a string), yet you are passing `Tag::all()` which is returning an object of all the tags therefore it is failing. What are you actually trying to do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587457/difference-between-eloquent-modelget-and-all

Comment: You could just `return view('tags.index', ['tags' => $tags]);` and access `$tags` in your view.

Comment: I know {{ }} is for echo, All i want is to access my TagController's index function that is bringing data from database. Then use that data as value in forms

Comment: @AshFixed if you know it is for `echo` then why would you try to echo an object? Secondly, if you want to assign variables in blade you use the `@php @endphp` tags and put your PHP within them. Nevertheless, to achieve what you want you can do what kerbholz suggested, that would be the cleanest.

Comment: @kerbholz my controller is already connected with  controller(FactController), this is just to get data from another controller(TagController) for a div

Comment: I find it a strange concept of accessing Controller methods in your view, that method looks like it belongs in your model. Personally I would add `$tags = Tag::all();` to your `FactController` method and pass it to your view.

Comment: @kerbholz Actually i am making something like a create post page that on the basis of choice of dropdown chooses controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, to actually set a variable within your template file, you need to use the correct blade tags:

```
@php
     $tags = new App\Http\Controllers\TagController;

     $tags->index()
@endphp
```

As it currently stands, you are trying to set a variable within `echo`.

As per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#php):

> In some situations, it's useful to embed PHP code into your views. You can use the Blade @php directive to execute a block of plain PHP within your template.

### However...

In all honesty, this is not the ideal way of doing this. You should *not* be accessing another controller within another view, you should in fact be passing the variable from the respective controller of the view as suggested by @kerbholz in their comment.