# Show countif mysql query table to html

Tags: php, html, mysql, countif, laravel-6

I have a countif query in mysql and I would like to show the table on my html. I'm currently using laravel 6.0 framework.

Here is the picture of the table i want to show:

[image: here is the picture of the table i want to show]

Here is my code in html:

[image: Here is my code in html]

Here is my code in the controller:

[image: Here is my code in the controller]

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of images. Also, please describe the problem that you are facing: what is wrong with the result that you are getting with your current code?

Comment: So I am having this error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array ". I just want to show the table on my website. Can you show me other ways to do it on laravel? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There should be numerous errors with `index` function in your controller. Specifically with how you are trying to assign `$count` a value. Read these: [Eloquent Methods all() vs get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587457/difference-between-eloquent-modelget-and-all), [Eloquent Selects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects), [Eloquent Ordering, Grouping, Limit and Offset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset), [Eloquent Where](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses).

Laravel has an excellent documentation, if you were to follow it - working with Laravel would become much easier.