# How to use append attributes with Laravel Eloquent and pagination

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

How can I use append attributes with Laravel Eloquent and pagination? We are trying to load the data from Laravel Eloquent, wherein we have to append attributes. So we want to query based on the append attributes, which works fine when not using skip and take. But we need to add the pagination and need the option of skip and take, but return an error.

**Model**

```
protected $appends = ['isSlaBreach'];

public function getIsSlaBreachAttribute() 
{
    return true or false
}
```

**Controller**

```
$overdue_tickets->skip($skip);
$overdue_tickets->take($take);
$res = $overdue_tickets->get()->where('isSlaBreach', true);
```

Need guidance on the same.

Answer (score 0):

but which error are you getting?

Note that querying over appended attributes it is not possible using directly the db: you are able to query over appended attributes by using Eloquent Collections.

I think in your code there are some problems:

1 - in the Model `return true or false` returns always `true`

2 - In the controller you should add a final `all()` in order to get filtered elements from the collection:

$res = $overdue_tickets->get()->where('isSlaBreach',true)->all();

Comment: return true or false is just for example it return on basis of logic which i hav not added. i trued adding all but it returns just two response however total no of records return is high

Comment: @gecche That above is not correct statement. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587457/difference-between-eloquent-modelget-and-all#answer-34587647).

Comment: why is not correct? the all() method is applied to the eloquent collection after the get() applied to the builder. i’m missing something?